# Retrieving vector data pointer for passing array of 2D vectors

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have OpenGL method :

```
glStencilFillPathInstancedNV(6, glyphBase,
                                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, "OpenGL",
                                 GL_PATH_FILL_MODE_NV, 0xFF,
                                 GL_TRANSLATE_2D_NV, xtranslate);
```

Where xtranslate should be an array of GLfloat where each consecutive pair of numbers represent 2 dim vector. In my app the data structure representing xtranslate is:

```
std::vector<glm::vec2> xtranslate;
```

How do I get the data pointer to this structure so that it's valid to be passed into the above  mentioned method as GLFloat*

Should I manually "flatten" the structure into array or there is some trickier solution?

[Glm is](http://glm.g-truc.net/) the OpenGL template only math library.

Btw , I have seen that OpenSceneGraph API has such a method for its vector structures , but I couldn't find the source for the implementation.

Comment: Is using C++11 allowed for you?

Comment: How hard does it crash if you just go with &(xtranslate[0].x)? :)

Comment: Just because I believe such an attempt will be useless I even not going to try it ;) Because it will get only a single pointer to a single float in the first vec2...

Comment: I'm pretty sure every implementation of std::vector stores its contents in an array. I would believe glm::vec2 is nothing more than a struct with two floats. If the float used by vec2 is the same as GLfloat, it might work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856364/c-passing-pointer-to-vector-element-instead-of-array-pointer

Comment: Ok , I will try it out .